# Android Passing big data on preview screen before user loads MainActivity with HashMap TransactionTooLargeException

Tags: java, android, file, hashmap

Hi everyone i am having a problem here so here is what i am trying to achieve.

Achieve:

Trying to create a Map and share it between activitys! And use it in MainActivity.

Reason:

Trying to avoid the big load of the data on the MainThread by loading the data in my SplashActivity into a Map and sending the loaded data into my MainActivty
so i can use it there to check it from user Input if it matches.

Problem:

Problem is that the data i am trying to load is this one:
http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/wordlist/wordsEn.txt

Which is a big wordlist and it takes a while to load in background. It has to be fast thats why i am trying to load it in Map before the MainActivity Load and then passing it when its done loading btw user is waiting for SplashScreen while load to the Map.

Getting error that the data i am trying to send true Bundle, Intent is too large.

Anyone having thoughs how i can pass the loaded Map into the MainActivity?

Yes i know i can use AsyncTask as the background thread...

Yes i know it can be done with Serialize but please show some examples of your thoughts.

Thanks for everyone who is trying to help!

ThePreviewActivity code:

```
public class PreviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Scanner scanner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Map<Character, ArrayList<String>> charCount = new HashMap<Character, ArrayList<String>>();

        //get Assets
        AssetManager am = this.getAssets();

        //create input stream
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            //open the word txt
            is = am.open("words.txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (is != null) {
            scanner = new Scanner(is);
        }

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            char firstChar = scanner.next().charAt(0);
            ArrayList<String> list;
            if (charCount.containsKey(firstChar)) {
                list = charCount.get(firstChar);
            } else {
                list = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            list.add(scanner.next());
            charCount.put(firstChar, list);
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putSerializable("HashMap", (Serializable) charCount);
        intent.putExtras(extras);


        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java code:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle!=null) {
            charCount = (Map<Character, ArrayList<String>>) bundle.getSerializable("HashMap");
        }
```

Error i am getting trying to pass it with a Bundle: Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 3560868 bytes

Answer (score 1):

First, please move all this I/O-and-parsing code to a background thread.

In terms of your `TransactionTooLargeException`, you simply cannot pass that much data around via `Intent` objects using `startActivity()`. You could:

- Store this data in a singleton, particularly since it will not be changing (presumably), or
- Wrap the data in a `ContentProvider`, and have other activities use a `ContentResolver` to work with that provider

Comment: Dont think about the IO right now the purose is diffrent can you show some example how to achieve what i am asking for?